# ICA (Independent Component Analysis) in matlab

Tags: matlab

Could you provide an example of ICA Independent Component Analysis IN MATLAB?

I know PCA is implemented in matlab but ICA, what about RCA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [FastICA implementation](http://research.ics.tkk.fi/ica/fastica/). I've used their R version before, I assume the matlab implementation does the same thing... On that page you get a description of the algorithm and pointers to more info.

Answer (score 1):

Dr G was right. 
Now, you are able to find a complete and a very useful Matlab Package (works also with 2013a version):
[FastICA](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/index.shtml)

Also you can find a another ICA and PCA Matlab implementation package there: [ICA/PCA](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38300-pca-and-ica-package). But I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is quite old, but it is worth mentioning that in 2017a, matlab introduced [reconstruction independent component analysis (RICA)](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/rica.html), which may come in handy for someone searching for ICA.